# Permanently change array even with page refresh

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm coding using Angular 2 (Typescript) and on my webpage I have different forms with inputs and when I submit those forms they trigger their own function that adds a new instance of an object based on the inputs to an array, which is then reflected in a table on the page that is generated from said array. How can I permanently save those changes in the array after the page is refreshed. The array `DPS` is imported from another directory. The `submitForm` function is in a Typescript file of a component that's separate from the Typescript and component of the main page (the HTML and rest of the Typescript). Below, you'll see my use of `onload="myFunction()"` for my overall `container` on the main page and the `myFunction()` function as well.

Here's the function that adds to the array:

```
submitForm(value: any){
  var val1 = String((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("dataPoint")).value);
  var val2 = String((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("ICCP")).value);
  var val3 = String((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("startDate")).value);
  var val4 = String((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("endDate")).value);
  let blah = new DataTable(val1,val2,val3,val4);
  DPS.push(blah);
  localStorage.setItem("DPS", JSON.stringify(DPS));
}
```

div for my main page:

```
<div class="container-fluid page" onload="myFunction()">
```

myFunction():

```
 myFunction(){
   let DPS = localStorage.getItem("DPS");
   if (DPS) {
     localStorage.removeItem("DPS");
     DPS = JSON.parse(DPS);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would something like local storage work? https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Seems to be solution. Working on @NitzanTomer 's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can save it in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage):

```
...
DPS.push(blah);
localStorage.setItem("DPS", JSON.stringfy(DPS));
```

And on page load you can check if you already have it:

```
let DPS = localStorage.getItem("DPS");
if (DPS) {
    localStorage.removeItem("DPS");
    DPS = JSON.parse(DPS);
    // you have an intance
}
```

---

#### Edit

Seems that there's a library for local storage in angular2: [angular2-localstorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage).

Comment: where do I put the second block of code? The `submitForm` function is in a Typescript file in a component for the form which is separate from the Typescript for the main page in which the table is located.

Comment: You'll need to register to the page load event, and do it there.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just not familiar with anything like that. Not sure where or how that is done

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I'm not an angular developer, but maybe do it in the `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Regardless, it's throwing errors `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` and `Block-scoped variable "DPS" used before its declaration` on line `let DPS = localStorage.getItem("DPS", DPS);`

Comment: Oh, my bad!  It should be: `let DPS = localStorage.getItem("DPS");`. I fixed it in my answer as well

Comment: That at least got rid of the errors. Page still gets rid of the changes when refreshing though. Might modify my question to help with that

Comment: I don't think that putting `onload` on a div works. It should be the load event of the document (`document.addEventListener("load", ...);`) or probably the angular way using `ngOnInit`

Comment: Oh hey, look what I found: https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage